# Yii Define relation to same model through other model

Tags: php, yii, relationship

In my Yii app I have 2 models, Profiles and Groups.
Each profile belongs to a Group defined by Profiles.GroupID that is a FK to Groups.GroupID.
Also, each Group has a manager (Group.ManagerID) which is basically another profile (therefore, it references a user_id in the table Users).

In model Profiles I would like to define a relation so that, for a given Profile I can easily retrieve the Manager.

Below is some sample data from the two tables that represent the 2 models Profiles, Groups:

```
Table Profiles
user_id  firstname    lastname     group_id
-------  -----------  ----------   -------  
1        John         Doe          100  
2        Walter       White        200  
3        Gus          Fring        100  
4        Biggie       Smalls       200  


Table: Groups
group_id   manager_id
-------    ---------
100        2
200        4
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use relations, you must create two `"BELONGS_TO"` and `"HAS_ONE"` relations one in `Profiles` model and second in `Groups` model:

for example in `Profiles`:

```
public function relations() {
    'group' => ...
}
```

in `Groups`:

```
public function relations() {
    'manager' => ...
}
```

and than you can get manager of concrete user like this `$user->group->manager`.

But in this case generates query with **two `JOINs`**, which can be slow if your tables are big.

Or you can use only one relation (for getting user group) and one more query for getting manager:
In `Profiles` model create public variable `$manager` and add it in your model rules (f.e in search)

```
public $manager = null;
```

and override method `afterFind`:

```
public function afterFind() {
    $this->manager = self::model()->findByAttributes('user_id' => $this->group->manager_id);
    return parent::afterFind()
}
```

**EDITED**

If you use the first method (two relations), you can override `Sort` object of your `DataProvider` (f.e. in method `"sort"` of your model):

```
public function search() {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $sort = new CSort;
        $sort->defaultOrder = 'someField ASC';
        $sort->attributes = array(
            '*',
            'managerLastname' => array(
                'ASC' => 'group.manager.lastname ASC',
                'DESC' => 'group.manager.lastname DESC',
            )
        );
        // .....other criterias
        $criteria->compare('managerLastname', $this->group->manager->lastname, true); // for filtering

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'sort' => $sort
        ));
    }
```

and in `CGgridView` columns add/change column

```
array(
    'name'=>'managerLastname',
    'value'=>'$data->group->manager->lastName'
) // be sure that each user has manager
```

and add also public property `managerLastname` in your model.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help, worked like a charm. However, I'm addressing a new challenge, that one of trying to sort by column Manager.Lastname which, instead, sorts the CGridView by User.lastname, lastname being the same column for both entities.

Comment: @user5276229 I added that part to answer. It available only in first case,  in second case yii can not generate query sortid by some attribute of manager such as profiles table not joined to result as manager.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's like this (untested):

```
public function getManager() {
    $this->hasOne(Profiles::className(), ['user_id' => 'manager_id'])->viaTable('{{%groups}}', ['group_id' => 'group_id']);
}
```

Place this function in the Profiles model.

Comment: So it has to be a function rather than a model relation?